# Scala doesn't find a class member

Tags: scala

When I compile things I always get an error:

```
value count is not a member of QueryStats
    def getQueryFrequency(key : Any) : Int = groups(key).count
                                  ^
```

The code is in one file and looks like this

```
class QueryStats(count : Int, totalTime : Double) {}

class QueryAnalyzer(queryGrouping : QueryLine => Any = QueryGrouping.kind) {

      val groups = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Any, QueryStats]()

      /** Returns all representant objects of query groups (unsorted). */
      def getQueryGroups() : Iterable[Any] = groups.keys

      /** In fact, returns query count */
      def getQueryFrequency(key : Any) : Int = groups(key).count
 }
```

I'm using scala 2.10.3 on Windows 8.1 64bit.

I just can't get my head around this.

Comment: I shouldn't worry...  I can't get my head around Windows 8.1 either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined constructor parameters for class `QueryStats` but not public fields.

You should either make `QueryStats` case class:

```
case class QueryStats(count: Int, totalTime: Double)
```

or add public `val`s manually:

```
class QueryStats(val count: Int, val totalTime: Double)
```